# Error in using my own Curl class in laravel

Tags: class, curl, laravel

i have laravel 4 installed in my wamp server. this what i did :

1-add this `"app/classes"` to composer.json.

2-create folder classes in app and put Curl.php class in that folder.

3-add this `app_path().'/classes',` to global.php inside app/start.

4-run `composer dump-autoload` in command in www directory.

5-for using like `Curl::help()` must add this alias to app/config/app.php aliases section `'Curl'=>'Curl'` .

after doing this when i return `return Curl::hello();` in router this page comes :

http://www.mediafire.com/view/h9489jr5s2699ty/err.PNG

my Curl's class : [Curl class](http://www.mediafire.com/view/t4xlu230z1i79u8/Curl.php)

any help??

Answer (score 0):

This is not how Laravel aliases works, you need more code (create Facades and Service Providers) to make it work.

So you have some options:

1) Remove the Alias from `app/config/app.php` and instantiate your class:

```
$curl = new Curl;
$curl->help();
```

2) Instantiate your class and bind it to the IoC container, in global.php, filters.php or create a file for that:

```
App::bindShared('mycurl', function($app)
{
    return new Curl;
});
```

And create a Facade:

```
<?php namespace MyClasses\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class MyCurlFacade extends Facade {

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() 
    { 
        return 'mycurl'; 
    }

}
```

Your Alias has to point to this Facade script file, like all the others you see in app.php.

```
'Curl' => 'MyClasses\MyCurlFacade',
```

And it should work like this `Curl::hello();`.

3) Create the usual (correct?) Laravel structure, which also includes a ServiceProvider to instantiate your class and bind it to the IoC container in the application Boot:

```
<?php namespace MyClasses;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MyCurlServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    protected $defer = false;

    public function boot()
    {

    }

    public function register()
    {   
    {
        $this->app['mycurl'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new MyCurl;
        });
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return array('mycurl');
    }

}
```

**THIS IS UNTESTED CODE, SO DO NOT EXPECT IT TO WORK IN THE FIRST RUN**